# Ordering elements in a line

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The periodic table has $118$ elements , assume that we want to order some elements randomly from left to right in $5$ position. What is the probability that the order will be oxygen,carbon,uranium,flor,cobalt if repetition is allowed and each element has equally probable?

My answer is $1/ (118)^5$ ,but it seems wrong to me, because all orders have the same probability. For example , oxygen,oxygen,oxygen,cobalt,oxygen $= 1/(118)^5$

I think this situation is also valid for when the repetition is not allowed $(1/ (118*117*116*115*114))$

Am I correct and please explan why all arragements have equal probability ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Can you clarify the problem? Specifically, what does "order some elements randomly from left to right in 5
 position" mean?

Comment: @DavidRaveh think the elements as distinct objects and we want to order by slecting them from periodic table to arrange a line which have five empty position

Comment: If you mean you are selecting randomly, both the formulae {with and without replacement) are ok